# Are different license keys required to activate Windows Sever 2019 SAC and LTSB releases?

Tags: windows

I have an unused Windows license for Windows Sever 2019 and the latest SAC install media. Can I instead use this license key with LTSB media, or does that require a different license?

Comment: That's definitely fair. I should state that I've previously called Microsoft, and after escalating my call they told me different licenses were required. They didn't seem confident about their response, however, and this is why I want to pose the question to actual IT professionals with first-hand knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes and no. I am very sorry.

**Technically**: Yes, you can. Practically all versions (not editions!) are useable with the same key.

**Licensewise**: Most probably not. To use the Semi-Annual Channel in the volume licensing programs, you need a valid Software Assurance for Windows Server.

Source: I have been coocoobananas trained. Over many years. I am so tired.